# Start speaking text

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech

I am wanting to incorporate the built-in text-to-speech tool on a mac to a website. Basically, the website will show a list of tasks, and in a different view mode, it will only show one task on the screen. In the "one task" mode, I want to to the "text-to-speech" software on Macs to read the task. I would want to do this on a PC too, if they come with a similar tool built in (unlikely).

Is there some JavaScript command I could use to tell it to start speaking the text, or is this way too advanced for JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any JavaScript command but you can use:

- http://www.jtalkplugin.com/
- https://github.com/kripken/speak.js

Both seems like a good option to gain the ability to 'start speaking the text'.

Comment: BTW: Why does the jTalk plugin output have that weird French/Scottish accent? :D

Answer (score 1):

Text-To-Speech is part of the os and not of the browser (or any HTML specifications for that matter). Thus there are several **hypothetical** ways of triggering it:

1. Call a js function that does a call to the underlying OS

   - I have not hear yet of any browser that implements that
2. Call AppleScript from JS

   - I have not hear yet that this is possible
3. Create a browser extension that is capable of calling AppleScript/Underlying OS/Shell command...

   - Probably your best bet but then the webside is non-function without the extension

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access OSX's text-to-speech feature directly, but if you're looking for a text-to-speech solution, you should look into speak.js:

[Speak.js on GitHub](https://github.com/kripken/speak.js)

[Working demo of speak.js](http://syntensity.com/static/espeak.html)